# How PHP or Laravel pass data to parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I am learning Laravel from a book called *Learn Laravel 5*. In addition, I have a PHP page (form.blade.php) like the following.

```
@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <p> {{ $error }} </p>
@endforeach

<form method="post">
      <input name="title">...
</form>
```

The book says it will validate data through the `FormRequest` code below when I press submit.

```
class FormRequest extends Request
{
    ...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required|min:3',
            'content' => 'required|min:10',          
        ];
    }
}
```

If the data does not meet the rules, it will store the error in the session. And the page will display errors through the `@foreach` code above. So how does Laravel or PHP know to pass data from the session into that `$errors` parameter?

Comment: it's called flash data from session, when the form request to the server and validation fails the validation error message store it on session and when the page redirect back to the form page, the $errors has value of errors from the form validation and remove it after.

Comment: It uses middleware [`ShareErrorsFromSession`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php) which is by default in the `$web` array in your `App\Http\Kernel` file meaning it runs for all routes defined in `web.php`

Comment: if you are learning Laravel I would advise you to learn Laravel 8. Laravel 5 is ... old... Apart from that, this is not a question that belongs on SO

Comment: keep in mind, when you use a form use the @csrf inside the form as well.  more info here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **$errors** variable is shared with all of your application's views by the **Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession** middleware, which is provided by the web middleware group. When this middleware is applied an **$errors** variable will always be available in your views, allowing you to conveniently assume the **$errors** variable is always defined and can be safely used. The **$errors** variable will be an instance of **Illuminate\Support\MessageBag**.

More info about flash data and validations here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors